# How do I train on time when I already know the date?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm looking to filter by a time interval.  For example, **from 9am to noon**.  It is unclear how to create that functionality in the training and action concept.  For example, I currently have this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should train it with `DateTimeExpression` and use the `DateTimeInterval` component to get the actual difference [image: Try it this way]

```
action (TestDateTimeInterval) {
  type(Search)
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)
  collect {
    input (dateTimeExpression) {
      type (time.DateTimeExpression)
      min (Optional) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (core.Integer)
}
```

Action Javascript

```
module.exports.function = function testDateTimeInterval (dateTimeExpression) {
  var dates = require ('dates')
  var whenStart;
  var whenEnd;
  if (dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval) {
    whenStart = dates.ZonedDateTime.of(
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.start.date.year,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.start.date.month,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.start.date.day,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.start.time.hour,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.start.time.minute,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.start.time.second);
    whenEnd = dates.ZonedDateTime.of(
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.end.date.year,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.end.date.month,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.end.date.day,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.end.time.hour,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.end.time.minute,
      dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.end.time.second);

// If you intend to return the difference between the number of hours
    return dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.end.time.hour - dateTimeExpression.dateTimeInterval.start.time.hour
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: That works well when I say the range, but when I say something this:  [g:Session] show sessions at (9AM)[v:time.DateTimeExpression]...Bixby will try to disambiguate the day.  What I want is tell have the plan prevent the day.  Just send the time.

Comment: You can add the following to the input

      default-select {
        with-rule {
          select-first {            
            sort-key (MIN) { binding(dateTime.date.day) }
          }
        } 
      }